# WPF DarkBlend Theme

Tags: wpf, themes

Actually I´m trying to add a dark theme on my application.

I´m testing DarkBlend Theme (https://www.nuget.org/packages/WPFThemes.DarkBlend/) and it works fine with x86 but not with x64. It loads the "Design" without any theme.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have any binding errors or warnings in the output window? (Maybe check your [trace settings](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409960.aspx).) Did you check the properties in the [WPF Tree Visualizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409789.aspx) or in the [Live Visual Tree](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/cdndevs/2015/08/07/live-visual-tree-in-visual-studio-3/) of Visual Studio, in [Mole](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d05cb44-8686-496b-9af3-4ed3deed3596) or in [Snoop](https://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/)? Can you post some simple code that doesn't work?

Comment: My code works, the problem is that the style is not aplied when I change to x64.

Comment: May I ask again: Have you checked the value source of the properties that are involved in the style when your application runs in x64 in any kind of WPF debugger? For example: If some `Background` isn't set properly then the error definitely lies in the source of the binding. You'll most surely see a difference in the value source, maybe because `Background` is now a default or an inherited value and doesn't come from your style. Regardless if your own code works or not (I can't tell that), you should try to find the root cause which could lie in the DarkBlend theme as well as in your code.

Comment: @haindl thanks bro! Based on what you told me, I tried in a back up version, and it worked for x64! Write an answer, so that I can set it!

Now I think it´s easier to find the problem! hehe

Comment: I have put my comments into an answer. Thanks for offering to accept it as an answer! :-) Glad I could help you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the value source of the properties that are involved in the style when your application runs in x64 in a WPF debugger like the [Visual Studio WPF Tree Visualizer](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd409789.aspx) or [Mole](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/1d05cb44-8686-496b-9af3-4ed3deed3596).

For example: If some `Background` isn't set properly then the error definitely lies in the source of the binding.

You'll most surely see a difference in the value source, maybe because `Background` is now a default or an inherited value and doesn't come from your style.

Comment: I uninstalled the theme, changed to x64, installed againg and it´s working now. o.O